# React-Rails 6 - Unable to import node_modules package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, react-rails

I'm trying to use an npm package in my react-rails project but can't seem to successfully import it. I first ran the following:

```
yarn add @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw
```

Then, I tried both of the following import styles:

```
import * as MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';
const MapboxDraw = require('@mapbox/mapbox/gl-draw');
```

However both of these generated the exact same error:

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw' in '/opt/app/myrailsapp/app/javascript/src/scenes/myscene.jsx'
```

How can I properly use a standard npm package inside a react-rails project? I've also tried moving those above statements to my `application.js` pack to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being due to using containers and only running `yarn install` locally on one of my containers. I have the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  myapp:
    # ...
    build:
      context: myapp/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development

  webpacker:
    # ...
    build:
      context: myapp/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
```

When I tried installing the package, I only ran

```
docker-compose exec myapp yarn install @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw
```

This installed fine, but **only** for that container. I also needed to run that on the `webpacker` container. It appeared as if the package was installed correctly when in reality the webpacker container did not contain the package.

Since installing node modules is apart of my Dockerfile, the fix was to run `docker-compose build`